# Custom android lint rules not being executed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

I have created two custom lint rules and verified that they work as expected with unit tests. However, when I try to run lint on the whole project with `./gradlew app:lint` these rules are not executed.
To verify that they are not executed I debugged (following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785161/how-to-debug-java-source-code-when-i-implement-a-custom-detector-for-lint)) and the debugger did not stop at breakpoints set in the Detectors.
A println set in the get issues of my IssueRegistry is executed (twice).
I have tried to run in `lint --list` and `./gradlew lint --list` in terminal but none of these work (lint does not exist, and --list option does not exist, respectively).
I have also tried manually enabling the lint checks in `lintOptions`, in the build.gradle.

**How can I get my custom rules to execute?**

**How can I see a list of the available lint rules, or gather information in any other way?** In inspections, searching by id my custom rules do not appear.

---

My lint code is in a separate module. This is the registry:

```
class IssueRegistry : IssueRegistry() {
    override val api: Int = CURRENT_API

    override val issues: List<Issue> get() = listOf(
        DispatchersDetector.ISSUE,
        ImportsDetector.ISSUE,
    ).also { println("creating issue registry!!!!!!!!!!") }
}
```

I also have a file in *resources/META_INF/services/my.package.lintrules.IssueRegistry*, which I think is not necessary (I've tried adding it and removing it). It contains `my.package.lintrules.IssueRegistry`.

This is the gradle for the lintrules module (Kotlin DSL, but I've also tried with groovy just in case, with no luck) (I have also tried VERSION_1_7 for Java):

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("kotlin")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion")
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion")
    compileOnly("com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:${Versions.lint}")
    compileOnly("com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:${Versions.lint}")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:$jUnitVersion")
    testImplementation("com.android.tools.lint:lint:${Versions.lint}")
    testImplementation("com.android.tools.lint:lint-tests:${Versions.lint}")
    testImplementation("com.android.tools:testutils:${Versions.lint}")
}

tasks {
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                "Lint-Registry-v2" to "my.package.lintrules.IssueRegistry"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I added the kotlin stdlib and reflect to remove some warnings about conflicting versions. It still complains about using different versions of the stdlib and reflect.
I use the following versions: android gradle=4.1.1; lint=27.1.1; kotlin=1.4.10; android studio=4.1.1.

In the app build.gradle I have added `lintChecks(project(path = ":lintrules"))` in dependencies.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in 27.1.1 for lint packages. Try reverting to 27.0.1. I experienced the same problem where custom lint checks stopped being executed and reverting back to 27.0.1 fixed it.

Comment: It must be something else, as I have the same problem with 27.0.1

Comment: @lotdrops are you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had the Issue parameter `androidSpecific` set to `false` and it should have been set to `null`.
According to the documentation: *true if this issue only applies to Android, false if it does not apply to Android at all, and null if not specified or should run on all platforms.*